# How set one parameter for weight & height if block have square/quadrant form? CSS

Tags: html, css

Now set of sizes of block look like: weight="811px" & height="811px". How set one parameter for weight & height if block have square/quadrant form? May be size="811px" or quadro="811px" :-) ?

Comment: In modern browsers, you can set the value via Custom Property (a.k.a. CSS Variable, see https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables), e.g. `<div style="--size: 811px;">`, and then use `width: var(--size); height: var(--size);` in its CSS code

Comment: @ Ilya Streltsyn I know about CSS variables. But for this issue it will be even more code, then size=811 or quadro=811 :-) .